# Groovy/Grails iterating the list and formatting the number using NumberFormat(US style)

Tags: grails, groovy, iteration, grails-orm, number-formatting

I have a Employee domain class and properties name,age,salary,annualPackage.
When I call `Employee.list()`. All the properties will be persisted.

Now I want to apply `numberformat` for salary and `annualPackage` properties.I can achieve it by:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(Employee.salary.get(0))
```

But How to format all the values of **salary** and **annualPackage** inside the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
def formatter = java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US)
def formattedValues = Employee.list().collect { 
  [
    salary = formatter.format(it.salary)
    annualPackage = formatter.format(it.annualPackage)
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
List<Employee> employees = Employee.list()
def formatter = java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US)
def formatted = employees.collect  { formatter.format(it.salary) }
```

**Note**: you should use `getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)` instead of `getNumberInstance(Locale.US)`